Fermi-Dirac Distribution for Multiple Species
If I have a system containing two types of fermions, what is the probability of a state of energy $E$ being occupied? Is it just the sum of two standard Fermi probabilities for each type of fermion?

The probability depends on the system and the ensemble and many other factors. Are you dealing with a system in thermal equilibrium? Has the system been excited by a laser? Is the system at a specific temperature? Pressure? Volume?

@hft, would you ask the same questions in the case of the Fermi-Dirac distribution for a one-component system?

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Maybe. It depends on whether I feel like making an annoying comment as opposed to doing OP's homework for them.

The sum, $n_1 + n_2$, of two Fermi probabilities, as you call it, can exceed $1$ and therefore cannot be considered the correct probability. Instead, for the case of two independent ideal Fermi gases having the same energy levels, the probability that the level is unoccupied is $(1-n_1)(1-n_2)$, and the probability that the level is occupied by one or two fermions is $n_1 + n_2 - n_1 n_2$.
